# How to synchronise Ganache-CLI accounts with Ganache-UI?

Tags: synchronization, accounts, network, ganache

When I launch ganache-cli for Port 7545, it will create 10 accounts by default.

```
ganache-cli -p 7545
```

However, when I then open the Ganache-Desktop-App, it will show different accounts and the accounts from the CLI can't be found.

This appears in the terminal from ganache-cli:

[image]

This is shown in Ganache Desktop-App:

[image]

Why aren't both in sync?

Comment: How do you run ganache-cli from the command line and ganache-ui on the same port at the same time? For me, they behave like separate instances and thus I can not run them at the same time at the same port.

Comment: I ran  "ganache-cli -p 7545" as shown in the screenshot in terminal and launched then the Ganache Desktop-App. It is listening at the same port as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: Yes, I can see, but when I try to do the same my ganache-ui won't start, because port is blocked. I have slightly older version of ganache, maybe there were some changes.

One thing you can try is to start ganache-cli with the same mnemonic key as ganache-ui is using as argument. The command is:
ganache-cli -p 7545 -m "candy maple cake sugar pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat"
Maybe it will help you somehow

Comment: @MikeA.Clearance this is the solution! works perfectly!

Comment: Glad I could help ;) I added previous comment as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you can try is to start ganache-cli with the same mnemonic seed as ganache-ui is using as argument.
The command is:

ganache-cli -p 7545 -m "candy maple cake sugar pudding cream honey rich smooth crumble sweet treat"